# get create date in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, kettle

We have some tables in mongodb which we are extracting data and loading into mysql tables through kettle. How do I get the create timestamp of a record from mongodb in kettle?

I read some articles where we can get date from objectid but I was not able to extract in kettle.
can anyone give me the syntax for extracting date from objectid or is it possible to get hidden create ts from mongodb meta layer in kettle?

Thanks,
Deepthi

Comment: If kettle doesn't have it, can you just create a script which adds a timestamp to every document?

Comment: I cannot add anything to mongodb , since I do not have permissions, it is just a source provided by another team.. Can I use any of the existing fields to get created date?

Comment: There are no hidden fields in a MongoDB document. Fields containing an `ObjectId` have a timestamp (of when and where it was created, not necessarily/likely the server time). If the collection used the default behavior, the `_id` would contain the timestamp, which is documented here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/

Comment: I'm not sure what's possible in Kettle, but if you can convert the $oid to a number (it's a hex number), or just the first 8 characters, convert to a number (you need the first 4 bytes representing the timestamp), you can then multiply it by 1000 for milliseconds, and set the field to be a "Date".

Comment: In Kettle, you can add a `System Information` step at the top of your transform and configure it to generate the current system date. This will add a Date column to the transform which will have the current timestamp in it. From your question tho, I think you're looking for the MongoDB solution @WiredPrairie gave. If not, I'll post an answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you all for the valuable inputs, will try them soon

Comment: Hello Brian, Could you please post me an example to add system information to get timestamp.it may be useful fo r me.  Thanks, Deepthi